# How to read a csv file present in different package to the program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

this is the structure:
:
this will have set of csv files inside folder say

My python program sits here which is trying to read csv file from data package.

this is what Im trying to do

```
f = open(datapoint.__path__[0],"drinks.csv")
```

datapoint is my

Im getting following error:

> ```
>    f = open(datapoint.__path__[0],"drinks.csv")
> ValueError: invalid mode: 'drinks.csv'
> ```

This is not even pointing to correct location. Can someone help me here?

Comment: did you read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) or try any debugging? The error is pretty clear

Answer (score 1):

You should concatenate the path first

```
import os
path = os.path.join(datapoint.__path__[0], "drinks.csv")

# ex: /home/user/abc/drinks.csv
```

then open the file with its path.

Comment: Thank you @Aaron. I was almost there.